# Python Selenium WebDriverWait() with element_to_be_clickable() does not work

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, element-to-be-clickable

Here's my code:

Part 1: initialize driver

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.headless = True

options.page_load_strategy = 'none' 
chrome_path = ChromeDriverManager().install() 
chrome_service = Service(chrome_path) 

driver = Chrome(options=options, service=chrome_service) 
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()
```

Part 2:

```
# provided that url and next_button_query is initialized and correct
# provided that there is a way to check for next page

driver.get(url)
delay = 20 # seconds
while there_is_a_next_page:
   next_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
   next_button_query)))
   next_button.click()
```

It still throws `element not clickable exception`. When I ask it to sleep for 1 second using `time.sleep(1)`, it works and I was consistently able to click the button to get to the next page.

Revised Part 2:

```
# provided that url and next_button_query is initialized and correct
# provided that there is a way to check for next page

driver.get(url)
while there_is_a_next_page:
   time.sleep(1)
   next_button.click()
```

However, this solution may not be reliable and could be wasteful if there are a lot of pages. Is there any way to wait for the element to be clickable and click it right away?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add minimum reproducible code so that people can help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you could switch element to be clickable to element visible and check it in browser view to see whats happening, dont just blindly add sleeps for no reason. But like Ajeet told there is not enough information, you did not provide URL as well.

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known issue: [See here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/40678/using-python-selenium-not-able-to-perform-click-operation?newreg=f17b6fd1a7784366b3bc7622099555ae), if your exception states that there is another element that would receive the click.